# Definite integral of hyperbolic function with hyperbolic arguments

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the following integral
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0} {\sinh[a \cosh(t)] \over \cosh[a \cosh(t)] - b} dt\,.
$$
I doesn't look too complicated but I have not been able to get a useful change of variables to make it look like something which could be in some integral tables.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: "Doesn't look too complicated"? Geez, what kind of integrals are you used to? Do you know for sure if this has a closed-form value? Where did you find this problem?

Comment: Perhaps it is relevant that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\ln(\cosh(a\cosh(t))-b)=\frac{a\sinh(t)\sinh(a\cosh(t))}{cosh(a\cosh(t))-b}$$

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to converge. The integrand approaches $1$ as $t$ approaches infinity.

Comment: So the question is easy.  Answer $+\infty$

Comment: Thank you all the answers! The problem came up in a renormalization context. It does appear to give $\infty$ but I was going to derive it with respect to $a$ afterwards so I was looking for an expression in terms of $a$ and $b$, but I guess it isn't possible.